# Convert hours,minutes to decimal and delete rows based on column value using VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I would like to convert Time Spent column in sheet of Excel to decimal value.

[image: Time Spent]

If the value is entered as 1 hour 30 minutes, it needs to be converted as 1.5(should not be appended by hours or minutes, just 1.5 will suffice).If the value is 1 hour , then the value should be 1.

Q.2) I need to keep the rows whose name corresponds to specific persons.Like I would like to sustain the rows whose name are = {Tom Cruise,Brad Pitt,Angelina Jolie,Selena Gomez}, and other rows should be deleted.

How to achieve this using VBA.Thanks a lot.

Comment: Please include the code you've worked so far and difficulties you are facing with it.

Comment: @shrivallabha.redij I  tried using InStr function.Like - If InStr(1, Cells(i, 3), "Tom Cruise") <> 0 Or InStr(1, Cells(i, 3), "Johnny Depp") <> 0 Then
      Cells(i, 3).EntireRow.Delete ,It is not working

Answer (score 0):

You may try something like this...

```
Sub ConvertTimeAndDeleteRows()
Dim lr As Long, lc As Long
Dim Rng As Range, Cell As Range

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

lr = Cells.Find("*", SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).Row
lc = Cells.Find("*", SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).Column + 1

Set Rng = Range("C2:C" & lr)

For Each Cell In Rng
    If InStr(Cell.Value, "hour") > 0 Or InStr(Cell.Value, "minutes") > 0 Then
        Cell.Value = StringToTimeDecimals(Cell.Value)
    End If
Next Cell

Range(Cells(2, lc), Cells(lr, lc)).Formula = "=IF(AND(B2<>""Tom Cruise"",B2<>""Brad Pitt"",B2<>""Angelina Jolie"",B2<>""Selena Gomez""),NA(),"""")"
On Error Resume Next
Range(Cells(2, lc), Cells(lr, lc)).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeFormulas, 16).EntireRow.Delete
Columns(lc).Delete
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub


Function StringToTimeDecimals(ByVal timeStr As String) As Double
    timeStr = Replace(Replace(Replace(timeStr, "hour", ":"), "minutes", ""), " ", "")
    If Right(timeStr, 1) = ":" Then timeStr = timeStr & "00"
    StringToTimeDecimals = TimeSerial(Hour(timeStr), Minute(timeStr), Second(timeStr)) * 24
End Function
```